# How to access any variable name according to loop index

Tags: c

I have some integer variables, I named them `n0` to `n9`. I want to access them using a loop. I tried this code to do that:

```
int n0 = 0, n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0, n4 = 0; 
int n5 = 0, n6 = 0, n7 = 0, n8 = 0, n9 = 0;    

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(digit == 1){
        n[i] = n[i] + 1;
    }               
}
```

I know it's not the right way, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: You don't need a loop to access **named** variables

Comment: i want to do it simple with loop if it's possible

Comment: `n[i] = n[i] + 1;` doesn't make any sense because it will just set all items to 1. You probably meant `n[i] = i + 1;` or some such.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer: declare an array instead, as `int n[10]`.

---

Advanced answer: it doesn't seem to be the case here, but in the case where you do need to use individual variable names of array items, for whatever reason, you can use an union:

```
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    int n0;
    int n1;
    int n2;
    ... // and so on
    int n9;
  };

  int array[10];

} my_array_t;
```

In case you have an old dinosaur compiler, then declare the struct with a variable name such as `struct { ... } s;`

---

How to use the above type in a practical, real world program:

```
  my_array_t arr = {0};

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    arr.array[i] = i + 1;
  }

  // access array items by name:    
  printf("n0 %d\n", arr.n0); // prints n0 1
  printf("n1 %d\n", arr.n1); // prints n1 2
```

---

Or you could initialize members by name:

```
  my_array_t arr = 
  { 
    .n0 = 1, 
    .n1 = 2,
    ...
  };
```

---

Silly, artificial example of how to use the above type to assign values to the variables without using array notation:

```
  my_array_t arr = {0};

  // BAD CODE, do not do things like this in the real world:

  // we can't use int* because that would violate the aliasing rule, therefore:
  char* dodge_strict_aliasing = (void*)&arr;

  // ensure no struct padding:
  static_assert(sizeof(my_array_t) == sizeof(int[10]), "bleh");

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    *((int*)dodge_strict_aliasing) = i + 1;
    dodge_strict_aliasing += sizeof(int);
  }

  printf("n0 %d\n", arr.n0); // prints n0 1
  printf("n1 %d\n", arr.n1); // prints n1 2

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",arr.array[i]); // prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  }
```

Comment: Comment rules says to avoid saying things like Thanks and +1, but luckily it doesn't say anything about saying LOL.

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do it is to declare an integer array and not 10 different variables:

```
int n[10];
```

Now you can access 10 int variables with `n[0]` through `n[9]`.

Comment: but this time I am not allowed to use array

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra Why not? That's a silly nonsense requirement, like "write this program without using your fingers, type with your nose only".

Comment: @Lundin: it sounds more like a silly interview question of the kind "write a hello world program without using a semicolon".

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra: no array at all?  You couldn't set up an array of pointers to those variables?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev That's a perfect interview question: it tells me that I should walk out the door and look for work elsewhere.

Comment: If you can't use an array you will have to type everything related to those variables 10 times. Once for each variable.

Comment: _I am not allowed to use array_. Why? Who says so?

Answer (score 0):

It is barely **not possible** to access your variables just like you want to, without any array.

All that comes to my mind, is to consider 10 separate cases for each variable, so:

```
int i;
int n0, n2, n3 ... n9;

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  switch(i)
  {
    case 0: n0++; break;
    case 1: ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use "real" arrays, lets use some dynamic memory instead (really silly but ...):

```
#define NUMVALS 10
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *values, *ptr, i;
    ptr = values = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUMVALS);

    for (i = 0; i < NUMVALS; i++) {
        ptr++ = 0; /* Set the values here or do what you want */
                   /* Ofc values[i] would work but looks like array access... */
    }
    ...
}
```

If you really have several variables that you want to access like you say, well save the pointers to them in an array (or like above) and access them that way, but it's still not by name. If you **must** access them by name well I think you're left with the pre-processor. I don't know of any other proper way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

```
int n[10] = {0};
/*or you can initilize like this also , this will make all the elements 0 in array*/

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(digit == 1){
        n[i] = n[i] + 1;
    }               
}
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using an initializer list?

Comment: Yeah... I know That How to use initializer list , I know How to use pointers also . but the guy who asked question doesn't know a thing. 

That is why I tried to tell him where actually the error is in his code